# Underlying exception: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instrument class because one of its supertypes could not be initialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2, & jdk to 17 and I am having the below error:

`Underlying exception: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instrument class because it or one of its supertypes could not be initialized`

Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Appreciate any feedback on how to resolve it or to debug this issue.

Thanks a lot

I tried to upgrade/downgrade the mockito dependency in the pom file (based on recommendations and on other working repos) and it didn't work.